# On Click Error?

Tags: android

Hi I didn't know where is my error coz Iv'e been using the same code over and over again but when I reach a certain point I got this error.

*Log

```
01-23 14:44:59.538: D/AndroidRuntime(8165): Shutting down VM
01-23 14:44:59.539: W/dalvikvm(8165): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414b88a8)
01-23 14:44:59.545: E/AndroidRuntime(8165): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 14:44:59.545: E/AndroidRuntime(8165): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-23 14:44:59.545: E/AndroidRuntime(8165):     at com.thesis.logipic.Gameplay.onBackPressed(Gameplay.java:2219)
01-23 14:44:59.545: E/AndroidRuntime(8165):     at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2139)
01-23 14:44:59.545: E/AndroidRuntime(8165):     at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2633)
01-23 14:44:59.545: E/AndroidRuntime(8165):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2373)
01-23 14:44:59.545: E/AndroidRuntime(8165):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1832)
01-23 14:44:59.545: E/AndroidRuntime(8165):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3949)
01-23 14:44:59.545: E/AndroidRuntime(8165):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleImeFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3915)
01-23 14:44:59.545: E/AndroidRuntime(8165):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3126)
01-23 14:44:59.545: E/AndroidRuntime(8165):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-23 14:44:59.545: E/AndroidRuntime(8165):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
01-23 14:44:59.545: E/AndroidRuntime(8165):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
01-23 14:44:59.545: E/AndroidRuntime(8165):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 14:44:59.545: E/AndroidRuntime(8165):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-23 14:44:59.545: E/AndroidRuntime(8165):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
01-23 14:44:59.545: E/AndroidRuntime(8165):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
01-23 14:44:59.545: E/AndroidRuntime(8165):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here's my code

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if (Beginner.beginnerStart.equals(1))
    {
        Intent openBeginner = new Intent("com.thesis.logipic.BEGINNER");
        startActivity(openBeginner);
    }
    else if (Learner.learnerStart.equals(1))
    {
        Intent openLearner = new Intent("com.thesis.logipic.LEARNER");
        startActivity(openLearner);
    }
    else if (Rookie.rookieStart.equals(1))
    {
        Intent openRookie = new Intent("com.thesis.logipic.ROOKIE");
        startActivity(openRookie);
    }
    else if (Novice.noviceStart.equals(1))
    {
        Intent openNovice = new Intent("com.thesis.logipic.NOVICE");
        startActivity(openNovice);
    }
    else if (Amateur.amateurStart.equals(1))
    {
        Intent openAmateur = new Intent("com.thesis.logipic.AMATEUR");
        startActivity(openAmateur);
    }
    else if (Graduate.graduateStart.equals(1))
    {
        Intent openGraduate = new Intent("com.thesis.logipic.GRADUATE");
        startActivity(openGraduate);
    }
    else if (Skilled.skilledStart.equals(1))
    {
        Intent openSkilled = new Intent("com.thesis.logipic.SKILLED");
        startActivity(openSkilled);
    }
}
```

The line 2219 is the "else if (Amateur.amateurStart.equals(1))"

The that is my last line of working code from graduate onwards it starts to show that error.

Comment: put your code here i think problem is that while you pressing back button  i.e. at com.thesis.logipic.Gameplay.onBackPressed(Gameplay.java:2219)

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException
01-23 14:44:59.545: E/AndroidRuntime(8165):     at com.thesis.logipic.Gameplay.onBackPressed(Gameplay.java:2219)`  Please post that method **only**.  If you really have more than 2219 lines of code in one class, you have a lot of problems in your app.

Comment: once check ur overrided method onBackPressed().There is an error.

Comment: already edited my post

Comment: wich value holds the "Amateur.amateurStart"? Have you debug this? I think this is null

Comment: it holds a value of 1 since I set it from Amateur class like this amateurStart = 1;